# Show event handlers in Intellisense

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

How can I achieve that? When I type - the event handler is missing in Visual Studio 2019.

[image: events in intellisense]

Comment: The image you posted shows an event displayed in IntelliSense. If you're looking for an event *handler*, those are often private methods but can also local or anonymous functions, none of which you can access.

Comment: Please don't spam the tags. You can't code a project in both C# and VB.NET at the same time. And the question isn't about either language, so there's no need for either tag. I've edit the question with the appropriate tags. Be clear and precise in your language describing what you feel is missing from the list.

Comment: Are you looking for Events or Event Handlers? The event handlers are methods used by a class object to handle events, generated by itself, its base class or other classes. The Event Handlers are listed in the class objects that subscribe to an event, not the class that exposes the event. So, post a better description of what you're looking for.

Comment: I just want the intellisense to show me events when im typing. E.g i have TreeViewItem assigned to 'item' variable, and when i refer to this variable i would like to see available events - in this example EXTENDED - but i dont see them, its very irritating. Hope now its clear

Comment: *expanded, not extended

Comment: Did you write `AddHandler` before that, if you're using VB.Net? @Heretic Monkey The language is relevant.

Comment: @Jimi Then edit the question. I still don't see anything *in the question* that is language-dependent.

Comment: Jimi, thank you. I actually use vb instead c# and its soo confusing..

Comment: "i have TreeViewItem assigned to 'item'"  Did you declare the "item" variable with the correct TYPE?  For instance, if "item" was declared as Object, you'd only see things that belong directly to class Object.

Comment: As already mentioned, post a better description of what you're trying to do and a definition of the objects you're working with. With the notion that Events and Event Handlers are two very distinct things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different cases where you will see the event in intellisense, for example in the first image adding an event handler to the click event of a button. In this case, you can see the event in intellisense.

[image]

However, when referencing one of the button's properties, referencing an event does not make sense in this case and intellisense doesn't show events.

[image]

If this helps, great. If not, be more specific to your situation.